# Create db user with limited privileges

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to create a sql 2008 database user that can backup and restore databases but NOT execute INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

Is it possible or the two operations are incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to assign them the role of `db_BackupOperator` to the login(s) to be able to do this.

They will be able to see the objects, but not the data in them or the code behind them.